# Which provider ethers.js is using as default?

Tags: ethers.js

In ethers.js the provider is 
ethers.getDefaultProvider();
Actually I am running nodejs on server and not using any node
Here which provider I am using?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question ("the provider is `ethers.getDefaultProvider()`... I am not using any node... which provider am I using?") is unclear. The way it is phrased, the answer is either "you are not using any provider" or "call `ethers.getDefaultProvider()` and find out". Please consider rephrasing it and including the relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/#providers-getDefaultProvider

> ethers . getDefaultProvider( [ network ], [ options ] )   =>   Provider
>
> This creates a FallbackProvider backed by multiple backends (INFURA and Etherscan).